# Merge conflict - No rebase in progress? Why am I on master?

Tags: svn, patch, git-rebase, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

I am in the middle of a confusing merge conflict between my branch (fix/disambiguate-property-meaning) and another repo's staging branch that would like to merge in my updated pull request. At present, I find myself on some master branch awaiting its initial commit, but I want to switch to my branch so I can commit to it, which I believe should automatically update the pull request.

This is what I have done so far in my attempt to resolve the merge conflict:

```
On branch fix/disambiguate-property-meaning
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/fix/disambiguate-property-meaning'.
```

`...`
`git pull --rebase upstream staging`

Resulted in the following messages:

```
 From https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp  
 * branch            staging    -> FETCH_HEAD
   57bb224..25e6d42  staging    -> upstream/staging
...
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in seed/challenges/01-front-end-development-certification/basic-javascript.json  
error: Failed to merge in the changes.  
Patch failed at 0001 fix/disambiguate-property-meaning, make JSON valid in basic-javascript.json #9096  
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch  

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".  
...
```

Before proceeding with editing my file that contained the conflicts, I ran git branch to reassure myself which branches I was dealing with and received:
`* (no branch, rebasing fix/disambiguate-property-meaning) 
   fix/disambiguate-property-meaning 
   staging`

This branch situation looked fine to me. (Did I miss something?) So, in basic-javascript.json, I deleted the git markings that indicated the conflicts. Everything else about my file looked exactly how I need it to look. I saved and closed it.

Back in my terminal, I ran:

```
git add basic-javascript.json    
git rebase --continue
```

I received the following baffling question:
`No rebase in progress?`

I have not found a clear explanation about this. What is this question really asking me to do? If it is a confirmation that the rebase was successful, as some answers seem to suggest, what a miserable choice in wording it!

What I want to do next is commit basic-javascript.json to *my branch,* then (automatically) update the pull request; which I believe equates to saying, then merge those changes from *my branch* to the remote upstream's *staging branch.*

How do I accomplish that? I am now somehow on some repo's master branch.

Answer (score 3):

`No rebase in progress?` means the rebase has finished. Whether or not the rebase was successful depends on whether or not it accomplished what you intended. Luckily, mine did.

The way I accomplished committing to *my branch* was to navigate back to the correct file path locally. I had accidentally initialized a git repo in the project's subdirectory locally, which is what created the mysterious master branch and the mysterious origin.

Lesson learned: pay attention to file path and do all pulls, squashes, commits, pushes, rebases and other git actions from within the proper (root) folder of the cloned project.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b387623c12f3f4a376e4d35a610fd3e55d7ea907), change the error message.

See [commit 244001a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/244001aa20d7a6411d8c920f34799df484d9a787) (21 Feb 2024) by [Harmen Stoppels (`haampie`)](https://github.com/haampie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2b5738c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b5738c867c1fb085a33544640bb9c52372ae2f7), 01 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/244001aa20d7a6411d8c920f34799df484d9a787): make warning less passive aggressive
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Harmen Stoppels</sup>

> When you run [`git rebase --continue`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/244001aa20d7a6411d8c920f34799df484d9a787/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L217)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---continue))</sup> when no rebase is in progress, git outputs `fatal: No rebase in progress?` which is not a question but a statement.
>
> Make it appear as a statement, and use lowercase to align with error message style.

So now, you would see:

```
fatal: no rebase in progress
```